# Defining an order on strings from an alphabet given an order on the alphabet itself

Tags: order-theory, formal-languages

Let $A$ be a finite nonempty alphabet, and let $\leq$ be a partial order on $A$. I want to define a partial order on $A^*$, the Kleene closure of $A$, based on the partial order on the alphabet itself. I know that when the partial order $\leq$ is in fact linear, then we simply have the lexicographic order. So my question really is, what is the analogue of the lexicographic order for general finite partially ordered alphabets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual "first point of difference" idea works even if the alphabet is only partially ordered. Given a partial order $(A;\le)$, we can define an induced partial order $\trianglelefteq$ on $A^*$ as follows: $\sigma\trianglelefteq\tau$ iff

- $\sigma$ is an initial segment of $\tau$ (possibly $\sigma=\tau$), or
- there is some smallest $n$ such that $\sigma(n)$ and $\tau(n)$ exist and are distinct, and for this $n$ we have $\sigma(n)\le\tau(n)$.

(In particular, note that this gives rise to the following situation: if $\sigma(n)$ and $\tau(n)$ are *$\le$-incomparable*, where $n$ is the "first point of difference," then $\sigma$ and $\tau$ are $\trianglelefteq$-incomparable.)